# Socket connection between Java and Objective C

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, sockets

I am trying to write a server in Java and communicate with it using an iPhone app (Objective C). The connection goes through, and I can write data to the server, but I can't read data back from the server. I get a notification that there is data to be read, but it's empty.

The Java code was taken mostly from [an Oracle example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

out.println("Hello World");

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    System.out.flush();

    out.println("test");

    if (inputLine.equals("Bye")) {
        break;
    }
}

out.close();
in.close();
socket.close();
```

And the Objective C client:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^(void) {
        NSLog(@"staying alive!");
        [[DABMultitaskingController sharedInstance] startTask];
    }];

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"10.0.1.189", 4444, &readStream, &writeStream);

    NSInputStream *inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    _dataToSend = [[NSData dataWithBytes:"This is a test" length:15] retain];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            NSLog(@"can read: %@", theStream);

            uint8_t *buffer;
            NSUInteger length;
            [(NSInputStream *)theStream getBuffer:&buffer length:&length];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:length];
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"bytes: %@", data);
            NSLog(@"string: %@", string);

            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
            NSLog(@"can write: %@", theStream);

            if (_dataToSend != nil) {
                NSLog(@"write: %@", _dataToSend);
                [(NSOutputStream *)theStream write:[_dataToSend bytes] maxLength:[_dataToSend length]];
                [_dataToSend release];
                _dataToSend = nil;
            }

            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
            NSLog(@"open complete: %@", theStream);

            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            NSLog(@"error occurred: %@", theStream);

            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
            NSLog(@"end encountered: %@", theStream);

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to use `read:maxLength:` instead. Works fine now.

Comment: where to add this as should have edited your question with answer.

Answer (score 1):

you never send a linefeed \n to the java side BufferedReader uses these as delimiters for readLine();

```
_dataToSend = [[NSData dataWithBytes:"This is a test\n" length:16] retain];
```

Comment: That is true, but it won't be the root cause of the problem.  A `BufferedReader` can (completely) read a data stream that doesn't end with a line separator.

Comment: seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051018/nsinputstream-getbuffer-length-doesnt-work just make your own buffer and use read I guess

Comment: This didn't solve the question above, but it did make the communication more reliable.