# Size of the NSInputStream buffer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use NSInputStream for receiving data using TCP socket connection. On the server side I send **data size** before sending of the **data itself**. on the iOS client side I need to extract first 4 bytes from the NSInputStream, because I need to check if size of data has received completely, but I have a problem with it:

```
...
case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
 if ( aStream == inputstream){    
   while (inputstream.hasBytesAvailable){                    
      var readBufferRef         = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>>()
      var readBufferLengthRef   = 0
      let readBufferIsAvailable = inputstream.getBuffer(readBufferRef, length: &readBufferLengthRef)
...
    }
}
break
```

After receiving of data readBufferLengthRef always equals to 0.

How it can be?

And how can I get size of the NSInputStream buffer?

**UPD:**

Code:

```
case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
            NSLog("HasBytesAvaible")
            var buffer = [UInt8](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
            if ( aStream == inputstream){

                while (inputstream.hasBytesAvailable){

                    var readBufferRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = nil
                    var readBufferLengthRef = 0
                    let readBufferIsAvailable = inputstream.getBuffer(&readBufferRef, length: &readBufferLengthRef)
                   //debugger: readBufferLengthRef = (int)0
                }
            }
break
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `readBufferRef` is defined as a "pointer to a pointer"
but never allocated, and therefore it is the NULL pointer.

What you should do is to pass the *address* of an 
`UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` as an inout argument to the function
(assuming Swift 2):

```
var readBufferRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = nil
var readBufferLengthRef = 0
let readBufferIsAvailable = inputStream.getBuffer(&readBufferRef, length: &readBufferLengthRef)
```

On return, `readBufferRef` is set to the read buffer of the stream (valid until the next read operation), and `readBufferLengthRef` contains
the number of available bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and answer! Unfortunately I still can't get the number of bytes in `readBufferLengthRef`. You can check full code segment in the UPD section of the my question. Guess it will help

Comment: Wow... And how it can be? Maybe I need to check something other?