# Algorithm of receiving data without getBuffer method

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use NSInputStream for receiving data using TCP socket connection. On the server side I send **data size** before sending of the **data itself**. on the iOS client side I need to extract first 4 bytes from the NSInputStream, because I need to check if size of data has received completely, but I have a [very strange problem with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045665/size-of-the-nsinputstream-buffer) - I can't get size of the `NSInputStream` buffer.

I think I need to put my received data to the temporary storage, something like `Byte Array` with append method and size property which I will able to use for receiving data completely.

**So my question is: which algorithm and class of temporary storage I should to use for this problem?**

*P.S. I know this is `too broad` question but I have no choice due to bug.*

Comment: Is this just a repeat of your previous question or can you now read the data size (solved in your other question) and now your question is about how to read that many bytes?

Comment: @rmaddy no, this is another question about best solution for this issue. I looked at the NSInputStream and NSOutputStream, but I can't use them due to them behavior - I need to be able to read and write to stream, but I can't do this using them.

Comment: But that's what I'm asking. What exactly is your problem? Is it the reading the data size (your previous question again) or is it reading the proper number of bytes after reading the data size? You have not explained at all what you current issue is nor explained why you think you can't use `NSInputStream` to read the data.

Comment: @rmaddy inability to get size of the NSInputStream buffer - exactly my problem, but now I asking another question which I described in this post, I'm trying to find another class like NSInputStream but with append method and working length property which I will able to use for my purpose. Also, I had a more general question - what is the more correct method to receiving TCP data in the described way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `NSInputStream` which means this is a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: @rmaddy but how can I use `NSInputStream` for manual writing(I need to read data from the first stream which connected to the socket, get number of bytes which have been read, and append received data to the second temporary `NSInputStream`) and reading(I need to read data from the second temporary `NSInputStream` when I need them(e.g. when stream has 4 bytes))? Please note that second temporary stream is only a trick for the getting size of the stream buffer.

Comment: Seems better update your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40045665/6541007) and close this one.